# How to modify Hibernate Interceptor in Spring Data

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

I have my custom Hibernate Interceptor implementation, but there is a dependency that I would like to use:

```
class MyInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
 private Handler handler;
 public void setHandler(Handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
 }

 @Override
 pubic boolean onFlushDirty(...) {
   handler.customLogic
 } 


}
```

And I would like to do smth like this:

```
   SessionImplementor sessionImplementor = (SessionImplementor) em.unwrap(Session.class);
   MyInterceptor interceptor = (MyInterceptor)sessionImplementor.getInterceptor();
   interceptor.setHandler(any custom handler implementation);
```

But I am using Spring Data and I would like to have this behavior for many Spring Data repositories.

I tried to use `JpaRepositoryFactoryBean` and `CommonRepository`:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Repository
public class CommonTransactionalRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements CommonTransactionalRepository<T, ID> {

  private final EntityManager em;

  @Autowired
  Handler handler;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    SessionImplementor sessionImplementor = (SessionImplementor) em.unwrap(Session.class);
    MyInterceptor interceptor = sessionImplementor.getInterceptor();
    interceptor.setHandler(handler);
  }

  public CommonTransactionalRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager em) {
    super(entityInformation, em);
    this.em = em;
  }

public class CommonJpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T extends Repository<S, ID>, S, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T, S, ID> {

  @Override
  protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager em) {
    return new CommonRepositoryFactory<>(em);
  }

  private static class CommonRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

    private final EntityManager em;

    public CommonRepositoryFactory(EntityManager em) {
      super(em);
      this.em = em;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
      JpaEntityInformation entityInformation = getEntityInformation(metadata.getDomainType());
      return new CommonTransactionalRepositoryImpl(entityInformation, em);
    }

    protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
      return CommonTransactionalRepositoryImpl.class;
    }
  }

}
```

but no luck, @PostConstruct does not work, obviously cause it does not work with @Transactional due to @PostConstruct works before proxy is created.

Answer (score 0):

You could either overwrite the `EntityManagerFactory` or assuming there is just one `ApplicationContext` involved get a hold on that inside your interceptor and obtain the required bean from it.

Comment: I think this is not a good idea, in general I think it should be possible out of the box in Spring Data.